# Merge and sort a list using merge sort

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

This is my code

```
def merge_lists(all_lst):
    if len(all_lst) < 2:
        return all_lst[0]   # get rid of the extra [] 
    left = merge_lists(all_lst[:len(all_lst)//2]) #[[2, 7, 10]]  ##[[0, 4, 6]]      
    right = merge_lists(all_lst[len(all_lst)//2:])#[[0, 4, 6], [3, 11]] ##[[3,11]]
    def merge(left,right):
        results = []
        while left and right:
            if left[0] < right[0]:
                results.append(left[0])
                left.remove(left[0])
            else:
                results.append(right[0])
                right.remove(right[0])
        results.extend(left)
        results.extend(right)
        return results
    return merge(left, right)
```

I am able to get the answer when i put this

```
all_lst = [[2, 7, 10], [0, 4, 6], [3, 11]]
print(merge_lists(all_lst)) # [0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11]
```

But when I tried to change it a little it doesn't work already

```
 all_lst = [[2, 7, 10], [0, 4, 6], [3, 11, 1]]
print(merge_lists(all_lst)) ##[0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 1]
```

May I know what's wrong

Comment: You realise you can do: `sorted(itertools.chain.from_iterable(all_lst))` for production code or if your lists are all sorted... `list(heapq.merge(*all_lst))`

Comment: @JonClements Good suggestion to use `heapq`, which yields an `O(log k * n)` algorithm where `k` is the number of lists and `n` is the total number of elements

Answer (score 0):

The third list is not sorted. When you do your final extend the 1 is inserted into
the end of the final list.
You should sort your lists before you call merge.

In other words your input should be:

```
 all_lst = [[2, 7, 10], [0, 4, 6], [1, 3, 11]]
```

They way merging works is that assumes that the sublists are ordered.

For example take those two lists:

```
left = [1, 3]
right = [2, 4]
results = []
```

merging goes like this:

```
if left[0] < right[0]:
    results.append(left[0])
    left.remove(left[0])
```

so now

```
results = [1]
left = [3]
right = [2,4]
```

but if you had:

```
left = [3, 1]
right = [2, 4]
results = []
```

merging goes like this:

```
if left[0] < right[0]: #false
else:
    results.append(right[0])
    right.remove(right[0])
```

so now

```
results = [2]
left = [3,1]
right = [4]
```

therefore you end up with an unordered final list.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by sorting first then merge I thought already sorted it in my else: loop then merge ? @zbs

Comment: I can't use any python sort logarithm here and I know it would be easier if I use python sort logarithm

Comment: For a merge sorting to work the elements you are merging should be already sorted in respect to the other elements of their list. So if you want to merge 3 lists those lists should be sorted before trying to merge them. Like that: [[2, 7, 10], [0, 4, 6], [1, 3, 11]]

Comment: So you are saying that this part is wrong ?
    left = merge_lists(all_lst[:len(all_lst)//2])
    right = merge_lists(all_lst[len(all_lst)//2:])

Comment: i was thinking of letting left = left[0] and right = right = right[0] before i put it into merge but it doesn't work  @zbs

Comment: Or if not flatten the list first ?? How do I do that then. I tried to flatten by sum(lst,[]) but there's an error saying can only concatenate list (not "int") to list @zbs

Comment: the lists are merged correctly. The input is wrong.

Comment: all_lst = [[2, 7, 10], [0, 4, 6], [3, 11, 1]]  u mean this is wrong ?

Comment: my function should work for all types of lists of lists ... So why is the input wrong ?

Comment: because the 3rd list is not sorted. There are many such examples like all_lst = [[2, 7, 10], [0, 4, 6, 1], [3, 11]]. Generally for a merge sort to work you should have your sublists sorted.

Comment: So how do I get my sublist sorted ? must I re - write another new function from what I had before or which part can I change?? @zbs

Comment: you can use the build in function sorted() or write one of your own maybe. Just sort each sublist before you call the main merge algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to sort a merged list, then you can use `sum()`, and then sort it:

```py
list1 = [[2, 7, 10], [0, 4, 6], [3, 11]]
list2 = [[2, 7, 10], [0, 4, 6], [3, 11, 1]]
list3 = [[10, 567, 34], [-10, -30, -109], [98, 10001, 5]]

def merge_sort(lists, ascending=True):

    if ascending == True: # If in an ascending order
        return sorted(sum(lists,[])) # `sum()` merges and `sorted()` sorts it

    elif ascending == False: # If in a descending order
        return sorted(sum(lists,[]), reverse=True) # `reverse=True` makes it descending
```

```
>>> print(merge_sort(list1))
    print(merge_sort(list2))
    print(merge_sort(list3))

[0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11]
[-109, -30, -10, 5, 10, 34, 98, 567, 10001]
```

```
>>> print(merge_sort(list1, ascending=False))
    print(merge_sort(list2, ascending=False))
    print(merge_sort(list3, ascending=False))

[11, 10, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 0]
[11, 10, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[10001, 567, 98, 34, 10, 5, -10, -30, -109]
```