# sorting error in python

Tags: python, sorting, recursion

```
def merge_lists(all_lst):
    def merge(left,right):
        results = []
        while left and right:
            if min(left) < min(right):
                results.append(min(left))
                left.remove(min(left))
            else:
                results.append(min(right))
                right.remove(min(right))
        results.extend(left)
        results.extend(right)
        return results
    if all_lst == []:
        return []
    elif len(all_lst) == 1:
        return merge(all_lst[0],[])
    else:
        return merge_lists([merge(all_lst[0],all_lst[1])] + all_lst[2:])

all_lst = [[2, 7, 10], [0, 4, 6], [3, 11],[123,88,7],[12,32,4,6,7],[34,22,1],[3]]
print(merge_lists(all_lst))
>>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 10, 11, 12, 22, 32, 34, 123, 88]
```

My code sorts the numbers in increasing order. But why is 88 not in the correct place? Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Is this some kind of homework, where you can't use built-in functions ? Seems you are not the only one working on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440361/merge-and-sort-a-list-using-merge-sort

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in your `merge` function. Consider this input:

```
[0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11] [123, 88, 7]
```

After some time, `result` is `[0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 10, 11]`, `left` is `[]` and `right` is `[123, 88]` -- and now you exit the `while` loop and just extend `result` with all the rest of `right`, which is not sorted!

To fix this, you could sort both `left` and `right`, then you don't need to use `min` anymore, either, as the first element will then always be the smallest. Or, if you can't use builtin sort functions, continue picking the minimum element from `left` and `right` until *both* are exhausted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to sort the list with a sort function, Python sort() works

```
all_lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 10, 11, 12, 22, 32, 34, 123, 88]

sorted_ls = sorted(all_lst)
print sorted_ls

output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 10, 11, 12, 22, 32, 34, 88, 123]
```

Answer (score 0):

please sort the list after adding all values.

`all_lst.sort()`

Answer (score 0):

you should change your code to this

```
def merge(left,right):
    results = []
    left = sorted(left)
    right = sorted(right)
    while left and right:
        if min(left) < min(right):
            results.append(min(left))
            left.remove(min(left))
        else:
            results.append(min(right))
            right.remove(min(right))
    results.extend(left)
    results.extend(right)
    return results
```

when you do `merge`, you should keep `left` and `right` list are ordered.